# How to display data from selected table in the same database in the form of table, in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a website where I am getting input of semester number from the user and I want to display the subjects in the semester they entered accordingly.
For this, I planned to create tables for each semester which would have the subjects in it.
For now, I am successful to retrieve data from one table. But I am required to get subjects as per the entered semester by the student.
Following is the code,which works perfectly for semester 5. Please suggest alterations as per the requirements asked above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- very important -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="subject.css">
    </head>
<body>

<h1 class="text-center text-capitalize font-weight-bold">Subject Information</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <br>

    <div>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <!-- <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;"> -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Sem"> Semester:  </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="sem_no" placeholder="Enter current semester" id=sem class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br>

</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>

<!-- TABLE DISPLAYED WITH DATA FROM RESPECTIVE DATABASE -->
            <div class= "container"> 
                <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                    <br><br>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Subjects</h2>

                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                                <th>Subject code</th>
                                <th>Subject Name</th>
                                <th>Faculty name</th>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root');

                                mysqli_select_db($con,'subjects');

                                $q= "select * from sem5";

                                $query = mysqli_query($con,$q);

                                while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                {
                            ?>  

                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $res['subject_no']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['subject_name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['faculty_name']; ?></td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                    </table>

</div>
</div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest alterations. Will be highly obliged.

Comment: You have a table for each semester? That's not going to scale up well, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a HTTP GET request and use PHP to get the value. Then use PHP to make the SQL query. Here it is in its simplest form.

I've added a submit button which submits the form and executes the HTTP GET with the parameters attached to the URL. You will see `?sem_no=x` after it is submitted. That's the [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

```html
...
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Sem"> Semester:  </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="sem_no" placeholder="Enter current semester" id=sem class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <br>
...
...
```

```php
...
...
//check the value was submitted and it is not blank
<?php if(isset($_GET['sem_no']) && !empty($_GET['sem_no'])) { ?>

<!-- TABLE DISPLAYED WITH DATA FROM RESPECTIVE DATABASE -->
<div class= "container"> 
    <div class="col-lg-12 ">
        <br><br>
        <h2 class="text-center">Subjects</h2>

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
<tr>
        <th>Subject code</th>
        <th>Subject Name</th>
        <th>Faculty name</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root');

        mysqli_select_db($con,'subjects');

        $q= 'select * from sem'.$_GET['sem_no'];

        $query = mysqli_query($con,$q);

        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
    ?>  

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['subject_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['subject_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['faculty_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
        </table>

</div>
</div>
<?php 
   //closing if
   } ?>
...
...
```

As mentioned in the comments earlier, this database design is quite poor. I know you are learning though. Have you considered having a subjects table that has a `Semester` column? Then you could do a query like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM subjects where semester_number = x
```

There are even better ways to do it beyond that but this would be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Sir, I did try adding a semester number as well in the subjects table  but I'm failing to retrieve the data from there as well. What I faced was, the semester which i was getting from the user wasn't getting read, and i was unable to show results accordingly. I'll be highly obliged if you give hints or code for the same.